# How to get multiple selected values of select tag via Ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax

**Hi Guys how can I send the value/s of `<select mutiple>` tag via Ajax Call? Thanks**

I have my `<select multiple>` tag here

```
<select multiple name='user[]' onchange="showUser(this.value)"> 
  <option value="1"> User 1 </option>
  <option value="2"> User 2 </option>
</select>
```

Here it the `<script>` Tag

```
function showUser(str) {
  if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);

        xmlhttp.send();
    }
 }
```

I want to send the multiple values from my back-end (getuser.php) then I call it by MYSQL SELECT(), back to my html page and show it to my index.php`<select>` tag

like this `<html>` Index.php

```
   <select id="txtHint">
     <option> 1 = select[value=1] </option>
     <option>2 = select[value=2]</option>
   </select>
```

**Note:**  These codes work only in *single* `<select>` tag but not in *multiple*, How can I run this in *Mutiple Select Tag* ?

**Thank You Guys**

Comment: You can't send array over GET . Try using json_encode

Comment: @manoj, Hi Sir Good Day, Thanks for the reply, Where I will going to use json_encode? In my Back-end? Thanks for the reply..

Comment: Use str = serialize(str); before xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);

Comment: and in getuser.php you can use unserialize(str)

Comment: You can pass multiple values on GET, simply use the different values with the same query parameter, like this: my.url/my.page?qparam[]=1&qparam[]=2&qparam[]=3